# Webform to start or cancel a relationship

Tags: webform-civicrm

I'm having trouble setting up a form that would pickup an organisation that a contact is a member of. 
I've set my form with 2 contacts, second being the organisation. The field "Existing Contact" is set to static, but when I type in the name of the person, the field doesn't change to list the name of the organisation, it just stay on not found.

I'm attaching a screenshot of my setting.

Any help appreciated [image]

Comment: Change the form widget to `Autocomplete`. Make sure the contact that you want to search from the widget is related as a club of the main contact selected in 1st field, i.e, Contact 1.

Comment: I'll try that, thnx

Comment: Jitendra - maybe change your comment to an ANswer